# cross-platform app development - onPress falied to call function that helps to show up hidden TextInout in react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native, constructor, cross-platform, textinput

I am very new to react-native (or any coding). I am working on creating a simple app that helps user to create book library and help them with keep count of books read or reading. In this app I am trying to create a button `AddButton` which will show a `TextInput` (with add and delete button) onPress.

I have been able to hide TextInput when someone first open the app but when I am pressing the add button it is not showing up TextInput view. Can anyone help wiht this problem?

Code part1:

```
export default class KeepCount {
  constructor() {
    this.totalCount = 1;
    this.readingCount = 0;
    this.readCount = 0;
    this.isAddNewBookVisible = false;
  }

  showAddNewBook() {
    this.setState({ isAddNewBookVisible: true });
    return isAddNewBookVisible;
  }

  hideAddNewBook() {
    this.setState({ isAddNewBookVisible: false });
    return isAddNewBookVisible;
  }
}
```

code part2 - app.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Text, View, SafeAreaView, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import KeepCount from "./components/KeepCount";
import BookCount from "./components/BookCount";
import AddButton from "./components/AddButton";
import AddBookName from "./components/AddBookName";

const state = {};

    export default function App() {
      return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <SafeAreaView />
    
          {/* top navigation */}
          <View
            style={{
              flex: 0.1,
              borderBottomColor: "#E9E9E9",
              borderBottomWidth: 0.5,
              alignItems: "center",
              justifyContent: "center",
            }}
          >
            <Text>Book Worm</Text>
          </View>
    
          {/* Main body */}
          <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            {/* add and delete book */}
    
            {KeepCount.isAddNewBookVisible && <AddBookName />}
    
            {/* add button */}
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={{ position: "absolute", bottom: 20, right: 20 }}
              onPress={() => KeepCount.showAddNewBook}
            >
              <AddButton />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
    
          {/* bttom navigation */}
          <View
            style={{
              flexDirection: "row",
              flex: 0.1,
              borderTopColor: "#E9E9E9",
              borderTopWidth: 0.5,
              alignItems: "center",
              justifyContent: "center",
            }}
          >
            <BookCount title="Total" count={KeepCount.totalCount} />
            <BookCount title="Reading" count={KeepCount.readingCount} />
            <BookCount title="Read" count={KeepCount.readCount} />
          </View>
          <SafeAreaView />
        </View>
      );
    }
```

addbutton  code:

```
import React from "react";
import { Text, View, Dimensions } from "react-native";

const screenWidth = Math.round(Dimensions.get("window").width);
const screenHeight = Math.round(Dimensions.get("window").height);

const AddButton = () => {
  return (
    <View
      style={{
        height: Math.floor(screenWidth * 0.125),
        width: Math.floor(screenWidth * 0.125),
        borderRadius: Math.floor(screenWidth * 0.125) * 0.5,
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "center",
        backgroundColor: "blue",
      }}
    >
      <Text
        style={{
          color: "white",
          fontSize: Math.floor(screenWidth * 0.125) * 0.75,
        }}
      >
        +
      </Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default AddButton;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try defining in state also initially like

```
constructor() {
    this.totalCount = 1;
    this.readingCount = 0;
    this.readCount = 0;
    this.isAddNewBookVisible = false;

    // init state here
    this.state = { isAddNewBookVisible : false };
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved this proble using "useState". I add below in my app.js file and it all started working fine.

```
  const [totalCount, setTotalCount] = useState(0);
  const [readingCount, setReadingCount] = useState(0);
  const [readCount, setReadCount] = useState(0);
  const [isAddNewBookVisible, setIsAddNewBookVisible] = useState(false);

  const showAddNewBook = () => {
    setIsAddNewBookVisible(true);
    // return isAddNewBookVisible;
  };

  const hideAddNewBook = () => {
    setIsAddNewBookVisible(false);
    // return isAddNewBookVisible;
  };
```